# Retrieve time tag with Jsoup

Tags: java, jsoup

This is my Html:

```
<div id="trestleLifts">
            <header class="tableHeader">
                <time>as of 4/23/15 @5:18 AM MST</time>
                <h2>Lifts</h2>
            </header>
```

I need the time Tag, but cant resolve it.

I try with this code, but the app crash

```
  Document docw = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
  Element doc = docw.getElementById("header.tableHeader");
            Elements h1=doc.getElementsByTag("time");
            String tit = h1.text();
```

Comment: Likely there's no element with id `header.tableHeader` - maybe you are looking for a selector like `docw.select("#trestleLifts time")`, and then you should pick the first element

Comment: Doesnt crash, but show nothing. I use this url      http://trestlebikepark.com/Lift_TrailStatus.html

Answer (score 4):

```
Element doc = docw.getElementById("header.tableHeader");
```

doesn't make much sense since there is no tag with `id="header.tableHeader"` attribute.

Since you are using CSS selector you want `select` method instead to pick `<header class="tableHeader">`.

```
Elements doc = docw.select("header.tableHeader");
```

Than just pick `time` element

```
Elements h1 = doc.select("time");
```

BTW you can do it all in one call via

```
Elements h1 = doc.select("header.tableHeader time");
```

---

Based on your comment in which you include address of page you want to parse, it seems that problem with this solution is that `<time>` is empty `<time></time>` after page is loaded and its content is later generated by JavaScript. In that case Jsoup will not be able to help you, because it is HTML parser without support of JS engine. You will have to use different tool like selenium webdriver or HTMLutils.

Comment: Or just `docw.select("header.tableHeader time")` -- i.e. you can stack up the selector instead of making multiple select calls.

Comment: Doesnt crash, but no show  time, the string result is; "Lift Trails"  I use this url trestlebikepark.com/Lift_TrailStatus.html

Comment: docw.select("header.tableHeader time") 
Show any result

Comment: Consider printing `docw` like `System.out.println(docw)` and you will see what HTML it represents. From what I see `time` tag placed inside `header` is empty `<time></time>` that is why you are seeing no results.

Comment: Then how put this time value in a textview?